# Accented letters are printed in bold type

Tags: overrides, fonts, style

For some reason accented letters are printed in bold type. An image is worth in thousand words:
[image]

The page is available at: http://elacebron.dipucuenca.es/index.php/k2/contact

I've been trying for more than an hour finding out where this style could be set.
Please does anybody give me a piece of advice about where this style could be specified or a good beginer tutorial.
Thanks in advance

Comment: May we have a url so we can see the generated source code? Or is this on a  local environment?  You are a little light on details beyond what you are seeing.  Are we talking about this? https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=839208  What extensions/templates are you playing with?

Comment: The page is available at: http://elacebron.dipucuenca.es/index.php/k2/contact

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will notice that not all of your accented/multibyte characters are emboldened.  The buggy behavior seems to be reserved to multibyte characters within specific elements / classed elements.

Declared in **override.css**:

> ```
> h1, h2, h3, h4, .very_big_white, .big_black {
>     font-family: LaneNarrowRegular,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
>     font-weight: 300;
> }
> ```

This means that the affected elements are `<h1>` through `<h4>` and any elements that contain the class `very_big_white` or `big_black`.

The trouble seems to be exclusive to the webfont **LaneNarrowRegular** because if I remove that font from the comma-separated list of fallbacks, the styling issue disappears.

After a quick Google, I came upon [fontsquirrel.com](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/lane) which allows you to enter text to test-drive the font before downloading.  When I enter `Próximo` the rendered output shows `Prximo`.  The downloadable character ranges [Western Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Latin_character_sets_(computing)) (default) and Basic Latin ([ASCII 32-126](https://cloford.com/resources/charcodes/utf-8_latin.htm)).  It appears that you might be using the Basic Latin and the wonky styling is side effect (perhaps someone simply grabbed the wrong one).

No matter what you decide to do, you are going to want a font that will reach up into the 128-165 range of [the ASCII chart](http://www.asciitable.com/).

You can simply amend the override file to omit the first `font-family` declaration, or you can download the extended web font and update your installation, or you can choose an entirely new font that supports your multi-byte character range.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple, the font-family you are specifying does not contain that character so the browser falls back to one that does, which is not available in weight 300; the result fallback font, default weight (400).

The solution, choose a font that contains all the characters you need.